# How to fix EnvironmentError when installing modules using pip?

Tags: python-3.x, module, pip

When trying to install `requests` or literally anything using `pip` it'll collect the option and then give me this ERROR every time.  I can't use pip to install anything.

```
C:\Users\evand>pip3 install requests
Collecting requests
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: path/to/ca-bundle.crt
```

Version of `pip`:

```
C:\Users\evand>pip --version
pip 19.2.3 from c:\users\evand\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)
```

Version of `Python`:

```
C:\Users\evand>py --version
Python 3.8.3
```

[Current Environment Variables (If this is related at all)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StlGO.png)

I have also tried the 'Repair' option using the Python Installer as well as uninstalling then reinstalling as a custom installation with 'Add to PATH' and the other options. That didn't fix the issue, so I deleted `pip` along with every module installed on my computer then reinstalled `pip`.  Nada.  At this point, I can no longer program with this computer because I cannot import any module in any of my scripts.  I am not sure why this issue suddenly arose.  Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Uninstalling the `pip` configuration file in `%appdata%/pip/` then 'modifying' python using the python launcher.

Comment: What does "modifying python using the python launcher" mean?